# Object is of type "unknown" error trying to display data from a Firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following a tutorial for reading and displaying data from a Firebase database, but it seems like the tutorial may be a bit out of date because I am getting an error when I try to display the data in the app.component.html template.

I have a simple database setup that has an "authors" record with some data about an author.
[image]

In the app.component.ts file I define an observable field based on this object.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  author$;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

And then I try to display this data in app.component.html.

```
<ul *ngIf="author$ | async as author">
  <li>{{ author.name }}</li>
  <li>{{ author.students }}</li>
  <li>{{ author.isPremium }}</li>
</ul>
```

In the tutorial it just works without problems, but when I try to do this I get an error on each of these three attributes.
[image]

I'm still fairly new to Angular and TypeScript in general so I'm not sure how to resolve the problem. I tried Googling for a solution but everything that came up seemed unrelated to this particular problem. Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by declaring `author$` as a type of `Observable<any>` although I feel like using `any` generally defeats the purpose of TypeScript.

```
export class AppComponent {
  author$: Observable<any>; // <--- changed this line

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Since this does work I am posting it as a solution, but if there is a better solution please let me know.